# Getting issue in login to Joomla administrartor

Tags: php, joomla

I have copied a Joomla website to another folder and changed the database also. The website runs successfully. But right now I am not able to login to the administrator. I am neither getting any coding error nor login failed message. I have try many option to sort out.

I changed the following in the configuration.php:

```
public $session_handler = 'none';
```

I also did changes in php.ini I added this line in the code:

```
session.cookie_secure = 0
```

I also change the password in the users table that also did not work for me

Can anybody please tell me why I am not able to login to the joomla admin

Thanks

Comment: which version you used?

Comment: right now I am not able to get that as I am not able to login to administrator @LifeTimeProgrammer

Comment: see this https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=717423

Comment: Maybe because you've removed the session handler, so it can't use sessions? (I think it's pretty vital to use the admin area)

Answer (score 1):

`session_handler` must be set to `database` - no idea why you set it to `none`. Also, make sure that Joomla is able to write to log and tmp folders. Please see [here](http://www.itoctopus.com/yet-another-login-loop-in-joomlas-backend).